# How do I add PATH to the ansible_galaxy_install module?

Tags: ansible, path, ansible-facts, ansible-galaxy

When attempting to install an ansible collection using ansible_galaxy_install, I receive the following error:

```
"Failed to find required executable \"ansible-galaxy\" in paths: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"
```

It is my understanding that ansible_galaxy_install is looking for ansible-galaxy on the the above PATH on the managed host and that I need to add the PATH where ansible-galaxy is installed.

```
which ansible-galaxy # managed host
/home/<user>/.local/bin/ansible-galaxy

- name: install collections | sbaerlocher.virtualization | virtualbox
  environment:
    PATH: "{{ lookup('env', 'HOME') }}/.local/bin:{{ ansible_env.PATH }}"
  community.general.ansible_galaxy_install:
    type: collection
    name: sbaerlocher.virtualization
```

This overcomes the first error, but then I receive a second error that the "ansible" module cannot be found (which is also located at `/home/<user>/.local/bin/`). It appears that the subsequent call is not respecting the PATH I provided.

```
fatal: [lenovo_laptop]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "/home/<user>/.local/bin/ansible-galaxy --version", "msg": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/home/<user>/.local/bin/ansible-galaxy\", line 44, in <module>\n    from ansible import context\nModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ansible'", "rc": 1, "stderr": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/home/<user>/.local/bin/ansible-galaxy\", line 44, in <module>\n    from ansible import context\nModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ansible'\n", "stderr_lines": ["Traceback (most recent call last):", "  File \"/home/<user>/.local/bin/ansible-galaxy\", line 44, in <module>", "    from ansible import context", "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ansible'"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

I also tried creating a links the ansible-galaxy and ansible, but it did not overcome the second errro.

```
- name: install collections | workaround | failed to find required executable | create symbolic links to executables required to install collections
  become: yes
  file:
    src: "{{ lookup('env', 'HOME') }}/.local/bin/{{ item }}"
    path: /usr/bin/{{ item }}
    state: link
    mode: u=rwx,g=rwx,o=rx # '0775'
  loop:
    - ansible-galaxy
    - ansible
```

**How can I get the ansible_galaxy_install module to use my PATH to find ansible-galaxy and ansible?**

Answer (score 0):

The issue was a result of mixing `pip` and `apt` installations of ansible, which use different file locations. Ran `pip uninstall ansible` and `sudo apt install ansible` to make my environment consistent. The search path for modules are displayed by `ansible --version`.

Credit to Vladimir Botka [https://www.mail-archive.com/ansible-project@googlegroups.com/msg59830.html][1]